# Passing the data from the structure into the table

Tags: abap

I am trying to pass data from a work area to a table. The idea is that I have declared the elements from the Screen Painter as data from a structure, e.g. The field with the name Banks would be as `gs_zfr_bn-bankl`, where the structure would be declared in the report as `gs_zfr_bn TYPE zfr_bn`, where `zfr_bn` is an global table.

Now I am trying to create a form which would serve to pass the data from the structure to the table, where the form would be activated from the event of pressing a button in the selection screen. I have been trying to create a code for that, however I am having an error. The code to pass the data is shown as follows:

```
DATA: gt_zfr_bn TYPE TABLE OF zfr_bn.

LOOP AT gt_zfr_bn INTO gs_zfr_bn.
  APPEND LINES OF gs_zfr_bn TO gt_zfr_bn.
ENDLOOP.
```

The error is that `gs_zfr_bn` is not an internal table and the append would not work.

Is there any way to pass the data from the structure into the table `gt_zfr_bn`, be that hard coded or via an method?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you already using `gs_zfr_bn` structure in screen paint. So you don't need to re-declare it. Just append structure to itab.

```
APPEND gs_zfr_bn TO gt_zfr_bn.
```

Comment: Hi @mkysoft, thanks for the answer. If possible, can I also ask you, whether there exist any method or way such as APPEND or Select, to transfer the data from the itab to a global table, e.g. in my case I tried APPEND from itab to zfr_bn but it did not work. I looked online and there existed the methods of export.

Comment: You can insert itab to db table with "INSERT zfr_bn FROM TABLE gt_ zfr_bn.". You can use screen PAI modules for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use APPEND without the LINES OF:

```
  APPEND gs_zfr_bn TO gt_zfr_bn.
```

(APPEND LINES OF ... this would append the lines of one internal table to another.)